# Remove columns based on a condition

Tags: r

I have a data set. I want to remove all columns whose value in the first row is less than 10. I have tried to make a reproducible example. Please see the code.

```
data_set <- matrix(8:100, nrow = 5)
required_data_set <- data_set[, -1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset the first row with indexing on `i`, create a logical vector by checking if the values are greater than or equal to 10 and use that in the `j` for subsetting the columns.

```
out <- data_set[,data_set[1,] >= 10]
identical(out, required_data_set)
#[1] TRUE
```